# How do I embed an http request in an html form if I want to target a specific website?

Tags: php

I wonder tho, how can I embed an http request url like myurl.php in an html form and then push the values onto the server using buttons
So I want to put (url.php), but I don't want the page to redirect to the url
Each time I press submit. I just want the data to get to the specified server.
And no I do not own the website in question.

Comment: Using jqery+ajax you can do that

Comment: See cross origin resource share (CORS). The server has to allow this by setting headers.

Comment: You could catch the click (or submit...) event on these links / butons in your page, make an ajax call to your own server and do a cURL request from there to the url with the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by ajax use this sample code

```
$("formId").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
       url: 'url.php',
       data: $("#formId").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
  })
});
```

or you can use [Ajax Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)